# Remove duplicate items in objects array with lodash.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, lodash

I'm trying to remove duplicate items using [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/docs) but I can't make it works properly.

This is the structure of an object in the array:

```
{
   label: 'tagA',
   value: 1
}
```

So let say I have this array:

```
var objectsArray = [
  {
    label: 'tagA',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: 'tagC',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 5
  },
];
```

I made this piece of code with [_.uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) function from lodash.js to try to remove the elements of array with the same labels, but it dosn't work as I expected:

```
    var uniq = _.uniqBy(objectsArray, function(o){
        return o.label;
    });
```

I based on some sample found here and there and lodash documentation of course but I have a lack of knowledge in this regard so any help it will super appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: *it doesn't work as expected* How do you expect it to work, and how does it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that you use proper namings, that code works for me:

```
    var arr = [
                {
                  label: 'tagA',
                  value: 1
                },
                {
                  label: 'tagB',
                  value: 2
                },
                {
                  label: 'tagC',
                  value: 3
                },
                {
                  label: 'tagB',
                  value: 4
                },
                {
                  label: 'tagB',
                  value: 5
                },
              ];

    var uniq = _.uniqBy(arr, function(o){
        return o.label;
    });

    console.log(uniq); // >> Returned an array with first 3 objects from array arr
```

Comment: I think he missed the array name in the first `.uniqBy()` argument

Comment: No, he passed `objectsArray`.

Comment: I see. But I don't see if he declared it, I see only unnamed array above.

Comment: It's a safe assumption that he did. If you think he might not have, you should leave a comment confirming that.

Comment: @torazaburo that's just only way to fail here, or maybe he forgot to import lib

Comment: Yes I declared it, sorry for assume you would know that I will edit that. And beside that finally it works even in the way I expose in my ask but was a bad initialization of array. Well, I hope any other guy help this question. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure you can use `uniqWith();`

This works for me

```
var data = [
  {
    label: 'tagA',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: 'tagC',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: 'tagB',
    value: 5
  },
];

var filtered = _.uniqWith(data, function(first, second){

    return first.label === second.label
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second example is just what you need [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy):

```
// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.uniqBy([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
// → [{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort I really appreciate it.